# Варианты Генераторы списков, возможные вариации, что существует?

Tags: python, list

Прохожу тест. Что из перечисленного может существовать в коде на Python?
(нужно выбрать все корректные ответы)

1. Списки списков генераторов генераторов
2. Генераторы списков генераторов списков
3. Списки генераторов генераторов списков
4. Генераторы генераторов списков списков
5. Генераторы списков генераторов
6. Списки генераторов списков

Comment: Всё может существовать, если использовать функции-генераторы (с yield). Правда, в пунктах 1 и 5 не уточнятся, генераторы чего нужны, но сделать какие-нибудь генераторы всё равно можно

Comment: @andreymal да ответ правильный все

Comment: Не столько тест на питон, сколько на способность распарсивать фразы вида "Косил косой косой косой " )